# Why is the acceleration of $m_2$ downward?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, free-body-diagram, string

[image]

The magnitude of the acceleration of $m_2$ is $a$.

It does not say in the question whether it is downward or upward.
But the answer assumes it is downward. So I think either it is badly framed, or it can be deduced that it is downward.

I can deduce its velocity is downward because otherwise the tension is zero, the question is asking for a non zero tension. I am able to prove why the two masses have the same magnitude of acceleration by differentiating the velocity vectors.

But I have no idea why is the acceleration of the second mass downward? Or, can it be upward?

Comment: Gravity pulls down and there isn't enough normal force to stop it. Did you draw your free body diagrams? One for each block.

Comment: Presumably the upward force F is in addition to the downward force of gravity, and presumably the upward force F is lesser in magnitude than the downward force of gravity. If the upward force F is greater in magnitude than the force of gravity then the block **will** accelerate upward (but also the rope will no longer be taut and the problem probably doesn't mean for you to consider this case).

Comment: @hft Why does accelerating upward makes the rope taut? I always thought the rope will remain taut as long as $m_2$ is moving downward.

Comment: Yes, I don't think I wrote anything to the contrary. If the force is such that the mass moves *up* the rope will *not* be taut.

Comment: What I am asking is the box moving down while the the acceleration is up.

Comment: If the acceleration is down, the box moves down. And the contrary applies. What direction have you chosen as positive and negative acceleration? What is it that you don't understand?

Comment: @josephh No, it is possible that the box is moving down and the acceleration is up.

Comment: you think something can move opposite to it's direction of motion? is that not a contradiction?

Comment: @josephh I have been saying the acceleration of the object, not velocity.

Comment: So the object is decelerating. Still does not explain what it is exactly that you are not understanding.

Comment: Why not show the full text of the problem rather than have people guess what is the question?

Comment: @josephh Imagine throwing a ball upward and consider the direction of its acceleration.

Comment: @TFR Yes. Like I said, the ball/object is _decelerating_. You still have not elaborated on what it is you’re not understanding.

Comment: "Yes, I don't think I wrote anything to the contrary. If the force is such that the mass moves up the rope will not be taut."       @hft I think the OP has made a mistake in his comment. He means to say that he doesn't understand why an upward acceleration will make the string slack though its velocity is downward.

Comment: @EternalLearner OK, I see. I probably should have said velocity not acceleration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand of the problem,
There is a downward gravitational force acting on the system, and also an upward force F acting on the mass below (In addition to tension T) and F+T is lesser than force due to gravity, else the problem becomes meaningless, implying that the net force on the downward block should be downwards.

The way the question has been phrased is probably a little confusing. However there will be no confusion if you understand that:
-Acceleration of the object is due to **net** force on it and if it is moving downward (no other information about initial velocity etc., are given, hence do not complicate it. Consider it starting from rest) as it has to, to make the the problem meaningful, the **net** force is also downward.

Both the **net** force and acceleration due to it are always in the same direction (downward in this case)

I hope things are clear now.

Comment: What if $m_2$ starts from rest and moves solely under the influence of gravity and tension for a while, and then an upward force is applied to that mass? In this case, can the net acceleration still be upward?

Comment: I am trying to figure out whether the net acceleration has to be upward, or the question is ambiguous. In the above scenario, can the acceleration be upward?

Comment: 'net acceleration' is not a very meaningful term There is only an acceleration that results from 'net force'. Acceleration depends on net force. Now the direction of acceleration will depend on the direction of net force. If upward force is higher than force due to gravity, acceleration will be upward (if it is already moving downward, acceleration is upward, meaning that it slows down due to upward net force)

Comment: In this case, the question is not very clear. However, for the string to be taut, the net force HAS to be downward. If not, the string will slack and there will be no role of the string and the other object in the question.

Comment: >"I always thought the rope will remain taut as long as m2 is moving downward. " 
  consider both the objects moving downward at some velocity. now, if m2 starts decelerating due to the application of an upward force, will the rope be taut? m1 will be faster than m2 after m2 starts decelerating, willn't it?